# Qt - QNetworkReply is empty after making request

Tags: html, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkrequest, qnetworkreply

I'm trying to get the HTML source of a webpage online, my code is as follows:

```
void Helper::start()
{
    QString url = "http://www.youtube-mp3.org/get?video_id=PnL4Z0ebcBc";

    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();

    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(QUrl(url));
    request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0;)");

    QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(request);
    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onFinished()));
    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this, SLOT(onError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
}

void Helper::onFinished()
{
    QIODevice * content = static_cast<QIODevice*>(QObject::sender());
    QString html = content->readAll();
    content->deleteLater();

    qDebug() << html; // It's empty!!
}

void Helper::onError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError err)
{
    qDebug() << "Starting On Error ....";
    QIODevice * content = static_cast<QIODevice*>(QObject::sender());
    QString error = content->errorString();
    content->deleteLater();

    qDebug() << error;
}
```

The `html` string is empty, I can't figure out why!

When I change the URL to Google's, it works, what's wrong? ( As I'm not getting any kind of error )

Comment: Check for errors with [QNetworkReply::error()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#error).

Comment: @OlegShparber Checked, no errors! Weird.

Comment: @MrEricSir My code works with other websites, but doesn't work as described above

Comment: @AlaaElrifaie then most likely it is a redirect. Check for [QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qnetworkrequest.html#Attribute-enum) attribute.

Comment: The suggested duplicate seems to have code for handling redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting empty response is because of the url redirection which you aren't catching.

The url mentioned in your code `http://www.youtube-mp3.org/get?video_id=PnL4Z0ebcBc` gets redirected to `http://www.youtube-mp3.org/?e=session_expired&t#v=PnL4Z0ebcBc`. So either you supply the redirected url in your code, or take some effort and handle the redirects.

First of all it's better to use the `QNetworkReply` class instead of `QIODevice` class for this purpose.

```
QNetworkReply* content= qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>(sender());
```

Then check if are being redirected using the `QNetworkReply::attribute` method.

```
content->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute)
```

I have written the working code, but I don't see the need to share it here since I have already told the key things. ;)

Also, I suggest you take a look at [this](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Handling_an_HTTP_redirect_with_QNetworkAccessManager).